# Compressing a string and storing it on a database as string for later decompression

Tags: java, oracle, compression

I have a huge string that I need to cache somewhere and since I cannot write to file my only option is to store this on the data base as text, more specifically, in the clob I have I'm storing a JSON file where I'm placing the compressed string under a certain key of that JSON object.

I'm compressing the strings but somewhere across the string manipulation something happens that doesn't allow me to decompress the data, so I'm wondering if I should encode the data to base 64 but that will lose compression.

What could I do to ensure I can store the compressed string in the database so I can later fetch it?

I cannot change the database, so I'm stuck with that CLOB field

These are my compression functions:

```
public static String compress(String text) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        OutputStream out = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos);
        out.write(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //ooops
    }
    return baos.toString();
}

public static String decompress(String bytes) {
    InputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.getBytes()));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        return new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //ooops
    }
}
```

Comment: A *cache* is used to limit the amount of work required to retrieve data, in order to improve performance. Compressing it and storing it in a CLOB would seeem to be at odds with that objective. At least it seems so to me.

Answer (score 2):

As you found out, you can't store binary data in a CLOB without some corruption, so encoding to text will be required.

Base 64 will, on average add 33% to the size of your binary data.  So you will lose some compression, but if your compression ratio is greater than 25% (this is often easy with particular types of text strings), then compression followed by base 64 encoding may provide you with a net storage gain.   Lots of CPU use though.....

Comment: Thanks David.  You're right - 25% compression ratio results in string 75% the size of the original, and of course 1/3 added to that brings it back to 100%, so you just need better than 25%.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert arbitrary binary data to a String without breaking it.  As you've already stated, if you want to store the data in a clob, you need to base64 encode the data (or use some other valid binary to text encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of other solutions, such as using memcached or other caching system? Or do you really want to mess around with compression?